# Grails how to parse text file?

Tags: grails, groovy, multipart

I would like to have the user upload a file inside a form and upon submission, open the file and read each line in order to grab information from it to store in the database. So far I am only able to make an object and extract bytes from it.

```
def  uploadedFile = request.getFile('name_of_file')
```

This gets me a commonsMultipartFile, but I am not sure if I need to stream the file into a buffer, or save the file into a temp folder and then try to open it that way.

`uploadedFile.getbytes()` will give me an array [71, 101, 110, 101, 114, 97, 108, 13, 10, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 13, 10, 83, 116....] which is not in a form I can do anything with.

I need to be able to open the file and read it line by line. Can I do that with the commonsMultipartFile - its options seem kind of limited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `CommonsMultipartFile` has a getInputStream() method which will return an `InputStream` on which you can call any Groovy enhancements, for example:

```
request.getFile('name_of_file').inputStream.eachLine { line ->
    /* Parsing logic */
}
```

Comment: To handle encodings correctly, you should get the charset off the `CommonsMultipartFile` with `getContentType` and pass that to `InputStream.eachLine`.

Comment: @schmolly159 I am getting this error using your code: `Class
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
Message
    grails.RunController$_closure1_closure3: method <init>(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V not found` any suggestions? thx.

Comment: @Universitas Not sure what isn't working.  I tried the code in an existing project and it worked for me.  You could always try a `grails clean` and restart the application.

Comment: clean was the source of the problem. Can't believe I forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

Save it to a dir first. Then parse and do what you need done.

Comment: How do you set that up? I tried `new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\My Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Grails\\resource\\test.txt").eachLine{
                line->println line
        }` but it is not working

Comment: I believe the file will be in temp directory until you explicitly save it to a permanent location. Then you can read it in.

Comment: I don't see a temp directory. I believe you have to explicitly place the file in a directory using `transferTo`. I have created a directory called resources and I placed a test file in that. I am having trouble opening that file and reading from it. Any suggestions on how to do this? I need to know how you 'read it in'. thx.

Comment: are you getting any errors? If so, please post them. Also please post what you got in your controller (and service if any) or test case as well. It might reveal some useful information.

Comment: `java.io.File rf= new File(filename); //open for reading` is giving me this error: `Class
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError
Message
    $class$java$io$File`